# PHP Two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

How can I make a two dimensional array with the following example using for loop:

```
$test = array ('D','D','D','D','C','C','D','D');
```

output should be like this:

```
$output = array(  0 => array('D','D','D','D'), 1 => array('D','D'));
```

thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

```
$test = array('D','D','D','D', 'C','C','D', 'D'); 
$output = array(); 
$myarray = array(); 
for ($i= 0; $i < count($test); $i++){ 
    if($test[$i] == 'D'){ 
        array_push($myarray , $test[$i]); 
    } else { 
        array_push($output,$myarray);   
    } 
} 

//OUTPUT: $output = (array( 0 => array('D','D','D','D'), 1 => array('D','D','D','D'));
```

Comment: This should be a simple `foreach` loop. You keep pushing `D` elements into an array. When you get to a `C` value, you push that array onto the result array, and start a new array for the next group of `D` elements.

Comment: you haven't provided the pattern. Do you want to find only consecutive 'D' in defined array and push it into a new array or what??

Comment: Btw, here is my code:



$test = array('D','D','D','D', 'C','C','D', 'D');
$output = array();
$myarray = array();

 
 for ($i= 0; $i < count($test); $i++){
  
  if($test[$i] == 'D'){
    
   array_push($myarray , $test[$i]);
   
   }
   
  else {
  
   
  array_push($output,$myarray);  
  
  
  }

 
 }




//OUTPUT: $output = (array(  0 => array('D','D','D','D'), 1 => array('D','D','D','D'));

Not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Your code is pretty close. You need to reset `$myarray` when you get a non-D, and you need to push it onto the `$output` at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be implemented using only one foreach loop.

```
<?php

$test = array ('D','C','D','D','D','D','C','C','D','D','C','D');

$temp = array();
$result = array();
foreach($test as $value){
    if($value != 'D' && !empty($temp)){
        array_push($result, $temp);
        $temp = array();
    }
    else{
        array_push($temp, $value);
    }
}

if(!empty($temp)){
    array_push($result, $temp);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: thanks Chinito and to all...I think 'for each' is the one I needed.=)

Comment: @eskapadero `for` and `foreach` are equivalent. The problem is that you weren't resetting the temporary array every time you started a new run of `D`.

Comment: Yes Barmar, I missed resetting the temp array..Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Here is the final code: Thanks everyone! I learned a lot from you.

Comment: $test = array ('D','D','D','D','C','C','D','D');
$output = array(); 
$myarray = array(); 

for ($i= 0; $i < count($test); $i++)
{ 
    
 if(($test[$i] == 'D')  ){ 
         array_push($myarray , $test[$i]);
    
 }
 else 
 { 
  
  if(!empty($myarray) && ($i != count($test)))
  {
   array_push($output, $myarray);
   $myarray = array(); 
  }
 }
 
}
 
 if(!empty($myarray)){
  array_push($output, $myarray);
  }

print_r($output);

//OUTPUT: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => D [2] => D [3] => D ) [1] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => D ) )